# How to change the dateformat using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a .ctp page .In that there have a button to load a div.

In that loaded div there have some datepickers..

The datepickers are loaded correctly.But i need to add 6 month to each date when i selected from datepickers.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var cnt = $("#cnt").val();
        for(var i =0;i<cnt;i++){
            $( "#date_"+i ).datepicker({showButtonPanel: true, changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, minDate: "0", maxDate: "+10Y",dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
                         onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
                        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(instance.settings.dateFormat, dateText, instance.settings);
                        date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);
                        alert(date);
                    }
            });
            $( "#format" ).change(function() {
                $( "#date_"+i ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", $( this ).val() );
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Here when i select a date from id `date_0` datepicker.
Then it displays date as `Tue Jul 30 2013 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`.

But i need to alert as `30/7/2013`.

How can i do this?

The date adding is correct but date format need to change?
Give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQueryUI date picker has a built-in date formatting function called [`$.datepicker.formatDate`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/%24.datepicker.formatDate).

```
onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 6);
    var str = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd/mm/yy", date);
    alert(str);
}
```

See above how you can use `$(this).datepicker('getDate')` to extract the current `Date` object from the datepicker. regardless of its current format.

Answer (score 0):

```
//getter
var dateFormat = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat" );
//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", 'yy-mm-dd' );
```

These would work for you.

Comment: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-UI-Changing-the-date-format-for-Datepicker-P1023.html

Comment: this changes the displayed format within the date picker itself.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3 Check out this article. Its really good.

**[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com)**

It is a lightweight (3.7 KB) JavaScript date library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting dates.

```
var a = moment([2010, 1, 14, 15, 25, 50, 125]);
a.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Sunday, February 14th 2010, 3:25:50 pm"
a.format("ddd, hA");                       // "Sun, 3PM"
```